# How to change the email adress on Latitude?

Tags: email, google-latitude

I took over the phone (Samsung) from my mom. It still shows her address on Latitude, even though it's my email address on the Gmail account.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the account in Google Maps.

1. Open the Maps menu.
2. Select `More > Settings > Switch Account`.

[Source](http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1645767).